# Insert Custom Data into a local DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

in this code i have already queried and cloned dataTable for processing the recoreds and avoid 
duplications without the nead to interact with database for every query (comparing new data with existing )

now that local dataTable is cloned (got all columns = table schema,from source table) from online db table

i whould like to insert values into the new created local Datatable , the data is already stored in local string vriables

```
static class ProcessedData 
{
    string name = "Rob";
    string webSite= "http://www.rcl.co.il";
    string title = "The Right Click";
}



dataTable localTable = new DataTable("LocalDt");
```

the idea was

```
  localTable.insert([Col_name], ProcessedData.name);
  localTable.insert([Col_webSite], ProcessedData.webSite);.....
```

how can i approach that, is that called bulk insertation ? 
(....just couldn't google on that issue without knowing the method name/term)

next move is to update Sql online table with new rows from harvested local data .

Comment: @MitchWheat sorry but stiil i do not see a clear way (example) as to how do i acomplish my task with the se results in google . the point is(to get it simplified) insert string into its designated column within the first empty row, of the LOCAL  DataTable as opposed to the online sql table (which is the next step... after filling the local table with new rows) i was refering to the stage of filling the local table with my custom data, hope it's cleaerer now ,excuse my language (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and the answer i found is :
in msdn 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc(v=vs.71).aspx

```
dataTableName.Rows[0][ColumnName] = value;
```

**UPDATE** (from another page of msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
yourNewDataTable = existingDataTableFromDataBase.Clone();
yourNewDataTable.NewRow();
yourNewDataTable.Row[0/or in a For loop=> currentLoopIndex][columnName] = value;
```